# jquery find all chaild DIV elements with li parent

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find all div with class **container**
That are be a direct child of li with class **row**

In this example only 1 and 2 are the correct div.
Not sure what am I doing wrong , here is what I tried so far:

```js
console.log('using: li div');

$('li div').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});

console.log('using: div.container > li.row');

$('div.container > li.row').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});

console.log('using: div.container ~ li.row');

$('li.row ~ div.container').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ol>
<li class="row"><div class="container">1</div></li>
<li class="row"><div class="container">2</div></li>
<li class="OtherRow"><div class="container">3</div></li>
<li class="OtherRow"><div class="container">4</div></li>
<li class="OtherRow"><div class="container">5</div></li>
</ol>

<div class="container">5</div>
```

Comment: Please use `console.log` instead of `alert`, it's much easier to see what's being returned.

Comment: You have it backwards, it should be `li.row > div.container`

Comment: console.log updated

Comment: This is not really a jQuery question, it's an ordinary CSS selector.

Comment: Why do you say `console.log("using: div li")` but then have `li div` in the jquery code?

Comment: because dumb :)  , fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. use `>` for direct child

```js
$('li.row>div.container').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ol>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="container">1</div>
  </li>
  <li class="row">
    <div class="container">2</div>
  </li>
  <li class="OtherRow">
    <div class="container">3</div>
  </li>
  <li class="OtherRow">
    <div class="container">4</div>
  </li>
  <li class="OtherRow">
    <div class="container">5</div>
  </li>
</ol>

<div class="container">5</div>
```